# connection refused from mail server

Tags: java, smtp

I am using a .bns mail server to send mails. I have confirmed that the server is up and running and the port number 25 is open for connections. My firewall is off and I don't think "telnet mailrelay.bns 25" is supposed to get me connected to the mail server. I have compiled my code and ran on command line. I have also ran in another IDE environment. It is always giving me the same problem: connection refused. The code works on another station and it's sending the e-mails fine. The exact code was working on my station before a certain time. I'm pretty sure it's some configuration issue. However, I do not remember making any changes to the system settings or internet settings. So I'm having a hard time figuring out what's wrong. The following is my simple test code:

```
private Logger      logger              = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String mailHost         = "mailrelay.bns";
    String mailFrom         = "yyyy@yyy.com";
    String mailTo           = "xxxx@xxx.com";

    String msg = "<html><body><p>hi</p></body></html>";
    String subject = "MailUtilTest";
    MailUtil mailUtil = new MailUtil();
    mailUtil.sendMail2(msg, mailTo, subject, mailHost, mailFrom);
}

public void sendMail2(String msg, String mailTo, String subject, String mailHost, String mailFrom) {
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", mailHost);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailFrom));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mailTo));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(msg);
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Message sent successfully...");
    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The following is the exact error message I get:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: mailrelay.bns, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.scotiabank.sco.sched.commonutilities.MailUtil.sendMail2(MailUtil.java:76)
    at com.scotiabank.sco.sched.commonutilities.MailUtilTest.sendMail2Test(MailUtilTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:381)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:243)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:488)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:297)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:229)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try connecting to port 25 via telnet from the box that is giving you problems
2. Check firewall and iptable settings on the mail server
3. View the [related logs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/util/package-summary.html) on the mail server

Comment: 1. I don't think telnet mailrelay.bns 25 is supposed to give me a connection since it's a mail server.
2. Firewall should be fine because other machines can access the mail server. My firewall is turned off.